# Code for obtaining monthly means of each month misses out on several means for months

Tags: r

I am trying to get the monthly mean values for several variables for 13 years of hourly data from 2004-2017 and create a new dataframe just for these monthly means. If done correctly I should have 167-168 mean values for each month from this time interval. In R, I am running the following code for collecting one of the variables monthly means and then creating a dataframe for monthly mean observations (should contain 167-168 observations, but only contains 36 random ones):

```
DT <- DT[,WTemp_mth:= mean(WATERTEMP), .(year,mth)][!is.na(WTemp_mth)]
#creates the monthly mean for water temperature and acquires the value

WaterTemp <- DT[,min(WTemp_mth), .(year,mth)]
#creates a new dataframe that should contain 167-168 observations of montly 
mean data but only contains 36 random monthly means.
```

Running the same code for another variable worked perfectly fine and a new dataframe should be created with 167-168 data points with showing monthly means. There is no numerical discrepancy in the variables that I am finding the monthly means for (as far as I know of).

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing some or all of `DT`. You can link to a file if it's a large dataset.

Comment: @neilfws Do you know how I can link a file?

Comment: something like [Share CSV](http://www.sharecsv.com/) maybe ?